# Russian sport idioms in business

Tags: идиомы

Are there any sport idioms (or war, or maybe some other topic) used frequently in Russian business discussions?

This topic came up in conversation, and we were unable to think of any obvious ones.

You can see some similar examples in English here: https://www.english-at-home.com/idioms/sport-idioms/

Comment: i'm not exactly familiar with business lingo, but i *suspect* that in Russia a criminal slang is more likely to be used in this field than military or sports terminology

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad and by definition can not have a single answer. You can ask about the Russian counterpart of specific English expression for instance.

Comment: Good question. And the answer is: yes, the saying "гонка с преследованием", borrowed from the motorsport, is oftentimes employed figuratively, including in business.   

... not to mention the chess idioms "быть в цейтноте" or "оказаться в цугцванге"

Comment: More idioms often employed figuratively, in business and beyond:
"сойти с этапа", "выбыть из гонки", "проиграть вчистУю", "проиграть по очкам", "оказаться в (глубоком) нокауте", "обрести второе дыхание", "уложить соперника на обе лопатки", "игра в одни ворота"

Comment: Thanks for the sports idioms! Very useful. I'll do some more research into criminal slang.